# What is the markup language used in Basecamp?

Tags: basecamp

You can enter text into Basecamp discussions, to-dos, and text documents. And you can use basic formatting like bold, italics, lists, and quotes.

[image: formatting options]

However, I once copy/pasted text from another program and saw an inline hyperlink appear ("some text" anchored to a web address). I really want to use inline links, but I can't figure out what markup is required.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29#Users) notes 37signals as Textile users. And there's [an old "product" blog post](http://productblogarchive.37signals.com/products/2007/07/use-textile-in-.html) that indicates that it *is* Textile. But, [the linked reference page](http://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/) is now defunct, appearing to be a cached version.

I tried the basic Textile link syntax and a variety of Markdown formats, but nothing worked.

```
"some text":http://example.com
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the `New Basecamp` launched, there was an article or blog discussing the editor; but for the life of me I can't find it now. Yet here are the basics of what it mentioned:

The editor is meant to be WYSIWYG, and does **not** interpret Textile or any other markup language.

It interprets hyperlinks in its own way (e.g. shortening them for display purposes) - you can't customize them in any way.

It also does some interpretation of pasted richtext (e.g. from MS Word) and attempts to auto-save.

That's it - it doesn't attempt to do anything more than this - keeping things simple & minimal.

I don't think this was exactly the answer you were hoping for :) yet I hope this info is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Open word, create a hyperlink, copy and paste it into the basecamp editor then you can get a nice [MyLink](http://basecamp.com)

Make sure you clean up the garbage code added by Word.

Yes, this is how you roll on basecamp. I think they believe the user should implement suboptimal features so they don't have to build (and maintain) the ideal ones.

Comment: Guillermo, while I appreciate your frustration, this is not an answer and I'm worried you're going to get downvotes. Would you mind adding your "answer" as a comment to my question? And possibly upvoting so more people are likely to see the question?

Comment: My answer is, go to word and create a link copy and paste. Yes its an answer. Just in case my answer was confused with a rant i reformated it.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to make a browser extension for facilitating the creation of hyperlinks?